# Enable comments also in FolderishType with plone.app.discussion

Tags: plone

I'm using `Raptus.Article` to manage contents on a `Plone4` site. 
`Raptus.Article` creates a new content type called `Article`, folderish.

I need to enable comments also on an `Article` type. `Plone.app.discussion` dis-allow comments on this type of contents.
How can I solve this? Is `MonkeyPatch` the only way?

Thank's

Vito

P.S. `Raptus.article.discussion` doesn't work

Comment: what version of plone.app.discussion are you using? IIRC this was solved some time ago; we have comments enable on folderish content types working.

Comment: Are you sure? In the versioning repo, on the master version, persists
https://github.com/plone/plone.app.discussion/blob/master/plone/app/discussion/browser/conversation.py#L66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik it's currently not possible, however...

Check:
https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.blog/blob/master/ftw/blog/browser/conversation.py#L54

It's overrides the default conversation_view of plone.app.discussion. (It's not a monkeypatch)

The important part is on line 54 (comment out part).

```
# Always return False if object is a folder
# if (IFolderish.providedBy(context) and
#     not INonStructuralFolder.providedBy(context)):
#     return False
```

zcml to override the default view. (https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.blog/blob/master/ftw/blog/browser/configure.zcml#L89)

```xml
<browser:page
    name="conversation_view"
    for="ftw.blog.interfaces.IBlogEntry"
    layer="ftw.blog.interfaces.IBlogLayer"
    class=".conversation.ConversationView"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />
```